# CSS conditional on custom field value

Tags: custom-field, jquery, css

I am looking to add some CSS rules to an ID conditionally on the value of a custom field value.

Specifically:

add to id `#firstimg` the rules:

```
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
```

provided that custom field `fl_status` has value `sold`

I suppose Jquery should be the best way to go here?

Comment: As-written, this question is unclear and difficult to answer. There are many possible methods to solve this problem. Please **edit your question** to include your current code attempt(s).

Comment: Chip can you list the possible methods so I can research more? I don't know how to make a start here. I think the question is quite specific with what I want to achieve.

Comment: I've posted on possible solution. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other context (which means you will likely need to adapt to your specific needs), I would consider [using the `post_class` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters). Using this filter, you can access the post meta for the current post, and conditionally add a CSS class to the post container.

For example:

```
function wpse129167_filter_post_class( $classes, $class, $postid ) {
    // Get post meta value for fl_status
    $fl_status = get_post_meta( $postid, 'fl_status', true );
    // If fl_status = sold, add a CSS class
    if ( 'sold' == $fl_status ) {
        $classes[] = 'fl-status-sold';
    }
    // Don't forget to return the array
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse129167_filter_post_class', 10, 3 );
```

Look at your post markup inside your loop. Look for this:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <!-- post markup will be here
</div>
```

For posts with a post meta key `fl_status` with a value of `sold`, that call to `<?php post_class(); ?>` will, among the usual classes, output the class `fl-status-sold`.

So, you can target this class with your CSS (directly in `style.css`, if you wish):

```
.fl-status-sold #firstimg {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```